# PowerShell Export-Excel - Format Cells As Text "@"

Tags: powershell

When I run the below and open up the Excel file, I see that all the cells are formatted as Text but the number still appears as: 2.38742+12.  I'd like to see the actual value as Text: 0002387429384723.

I'm using PowerShell 5.1 and the Export-Excel module with Excel 2016.

```
$xl = "0002387429384723" | Export-Excel -Path "c:\temp\file.xlsx" -WorksheetName "Sheet1" -Numberformat "@" -PassThru

$xlSheet = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"]
$xlSheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns()

Close-ExcelPackage $xl
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  Any guidance on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the -NoNumberConversion * switch to prevent number conversion for all columns.  If you want only specific columns to act this way, just replace the wildcard with the names of the columns.  This allows values to have leading zeros and prevents the scientific notation display.

Comment: Thanks, for specific column name syntax is : `-NoNumberConversion 'Column name1','Column name2'`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by putting my data in a DataTable and importing the DataTable using the code below.  This approach seems to preserve the cell formatting as Text.

```
$sheetName = "Sheet1"
$xl = Export-Excel -Path "c:\temp\file.xlsx" -WorksheetName $sheetName -PassThru

$null = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[$sheetName ].Cells[1,1].LoadFromDataTable($dt, $true)

$null = Export-Excel -ExcelPackage $xl -WorksheetName $sheetName -PassThru
...
Close-ExcelPackage $xl
```